# Is the beta distribution a good representative of the family of log-concave distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions, beta-function

When considering log-concave distributions within the range [0,1], if I utilize the beta distribution with parameters $\alpha, \beta \geq 1$, does this choice encompass all potential shapes generated by the log-concave distributions? Or are there shapes that would be overlooked by this assumption?
Thanks